# No module named '_lzma'

Tags: python, pylzma

I'm working on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I'm trying to debug my python code within a virtual environment created with the help of pyenv and poetry 1.1.13 as a package manager.

I get this message in the debugging console trying to import

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'

when i try to import _lzma using:

```
from _lzma import *
```

From what I can gather its related to package installation errors, I have tried installing it manually but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [pyenv wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#how-to-build-cpython-with-framework-support-on-os-x), you should install the desired python version with `--enable-framework flag`.

```
PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-framework" pyenv install 3.6.7
```

The reason is that the module you're trying to use is implemented in C, and CPython with shared libraries will be built with the aforementioned flag.

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

**frist**

```
yum install xz-devel
yum install python-backports-lzma
pip install backports.lzma
```

**second go to file where exeception originated**

```
cd /usr/local/lib/python3.8
vi lzma.py
```

**finally**
modify about line 27 to

```
try:
    from _lzma import *
    from _lzma import _encode_filter_properties, _decode_filter_properties
except ImportError:
    from backports.lzma import *
    from backports.lzma import _encode_filter_properties, _decode_filter_properties
```

it‘s work！I had to search for hours to get this problem to be solved.

Credit: [Yolo5 issues](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/1298)